# project debugs but will not be installed on device

Tags: android, android-studio

i connect android studio to my phone via usb.
my android project will be work correctly when i **debug** it. 
but when I'm clicking on apk file for **installing** it quickly stops and
i will receive "unfortunately has stopped" .
and there is no issue on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same project syncd on your android studio with same package name on your Android phone you will be able to debug it.

Be careful that this DOES NOT guarantee that you have the same code version on your IDE and in your device.

> and there is no issue on logcat

This is highly unlikely. 
Please, proceed with these comands on your prompt/bash/terminal:
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb logcat -c
adb logcat (and press "play" button)

See logs.